# When I use fill function to close and fill a path, I found that a tiny part is not be filled,why?

Tags: javascript, canvas

When I use fill function to close and fill a path, I found that a tiny part is not be filled,why? [Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guhJ4.png)

I want to know what induce this problem and how to solve it.

This problem does not always appear, If I change the params for drawing, this problem probably does not appear. The code is as follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="xContent"></div>
  <canvas width="1600" height="1600" id="canvas-element"></canvas>
  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-element')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(209.4390625 * 2, 495 * 2, 209.4390625 * 2, 235 * 2, 228.265625 * 2, 235 * 2)
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(247.09218750000002 * 2, 235 * 2, 247.09218750000002 * 2, 40 * 2, 265.91875000000005 * 2, 40 * 2)
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(284.74531250000007 * 2, 40 * 2, 284.74531250000007 * 2, 560 * 2, 303.57187500000003 * 2, 560 * 2)
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(322.3984375 * 2, 560 * 2, 322.3984375 * 2, 235 * 2, 341.225 * 2, 235 * 2)
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.05156250000005 * 2, 235 * 2, 360.05156250000005 * 2, 365 * 2, 378.878125 * 2, 365 * 2)
    ctx.lineTo(378.878125 * 2, 365 * 2 + 600)
    ctx.lineTo(209.4390625 * 2, 365 * 2 + 600)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()

    ctx.fill()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, your exact code as shown put into a jsfiddle, does not show this missing part for me in either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @CBroe It does for me if I open it in fullscreen.

Comment: @CBroe It also shows on the preview, but you have to scroll a bit to the right where you can see that the stroke is there, but some fill is missing as if it has closed the path with a straight line.

Comment: I have to second CBroe here, I'm not seeing it in this [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rt6kxg1o/show), created from the posted code.

Comment: It's weird that this problem will appear in Chrome, but won't appear in Safari. My computer is 14 inch Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip, and I use the built-in display

Comment: @Bruce: I've tried with Firefox (116.02), Chrome, and Edge, (both 115), all on Ubuntu 23.04 and I can't reproduce the problem described.

Comment: I did open https://crbug.com/1472230

Answer (score 3):

This is a apparently a rounding bug affecting (maybe only on macOS ARM devices) Chrome and other Chromium based browsers, which only concerns the GPU Accelerated path as can be seen in the below snippet where we force using the CPU rendering path.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-element')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true })
ctx.bezierCurveTo(209.4390625 * 2, 495 * 2, 209.4390625 * 2, 235 * 2, 228.265625 * 2, 235 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(247.09218750000002 * 2, 235 * 2, 247.09218750000002 * 2, 40 * 2, 265.91875000000005 * 2, 40 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(284.74531250000007 * 2, 40 * 2, 284.74531250000007 * 2, 560 * 2, 303.57187500000003 * 2, 560 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(322.3984375 * 2, 560 * 2, 322.3984375 * 2, 235 * 2, 341.225 * 2, 235 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.05156250000005 * 2, 235 * 2, 360.05156250000005 * 2, 365 * 2, 378.878125 * 2, 365 * 2)
ctx.lineTo(378.878125 * 2, 365 * 2 + 600)
ctx.lineTo(209.4390625 * 2, 365 * 2 + 600)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.stroke()

ctx.fill()
```

```html
<canvas width="1600" height="1600" id="canvas-element"></canvas>
```

But this means that you will lose all the benefits from hardware acceleration, so a better workaround might be to use smaller precision numbers in your coords.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-element')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.bezierCurveTo(209 * 2, 495 * 2, 209 * 2, 235 * 2, 228 * 2, 235 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(247 * 2, 235 * 2, 247 * 2, 40 * 2, 265 * 2, 40 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(284 * 2, 40 * 2, 284 * 2, 560 * 2, 303 * 2, 560 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(322 * 2, 560 * 2, 322 * 2, 235 * 2, 341 * 2, 235 * 2)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(360 * 2, 235 * 2, 360 * 2, 365 * 2, 378 * 2, 365 * 2)
ctx.lineTo(378 * 2, 365 * 2 + 600)
ctx.lineTo(209 * 2, 365 * 2 + 600)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.stroke()

ctx.fill()
```

```html
<canvas width="1600" height="1600" id="canvas-element"></canvas>
```

Since this got me curious, I did [open an issue](https://crbug.com/1472230).